# How do you declare a string-indexed (associative) array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
type bla = Array<string>[string] //this yields an error, saying that the array cannot be indexed using a string.

const blubb: bla = []
blubb["edfefe"] = "2"
```

how can I accomplish this the TypeScript way?

I tried the above code and variations of that with no success

Comment: You should probably not be using an *array* at all; instead you want an object with a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), like `type Bla = {[k: string]: string}; const blubb: Bla = {}; blubb["edfefe"] = "2";` the last line could also be written `blubb.edfefe = "2";` instead.

Comment: TypeScript (and JavaScript) does not have "associative arrays". It has objects and maps. TypeScript also refers to the former as Record types.

Comment: no, i do not want an object, for a very good reason

Comment: What is that good reason?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev of course javascript does

Comment: If you're hoping to have answers to yours, yes, you are :)

Comment: @muzzletov certainly **yes** you are here to answer clarifying questions about your post

Comment: @muzzletov I have bad news for you, arrays are themselves objects in Javascript (and I suppose in many other languages as well...)

Comment: As mentioned in [ask] you should be responding to feedback in good faith.  What is the reason you can't use an object?

Comment: @Jake okay. thanks for letting me know. i didnt know. my bad. :D jcalz - is that how i should answer to comments like that?

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't know why you don't want an object; if you answered that I missed the answer, sorry.  It also doesn't seem likely that further discussion here will be fruitful for either of us, so I'll disengage now.

Comment: But _JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays_. It has primitives, and it has objects. Arrays in JS are simply a particular kind of object that are indexed with numeric keys.

Comment: @muzzletov We are here to donate our free time to helping you, because we like helping people. You can make that easy or hard. If you make it easy, we will help you. The choice is yours.

Comment: I'm afraid that, so far, you have not explained anything to me or anyone else. I have already had to flag one of you comments for swearing at the people who are trying to help you.

Comment: Darryl is not wrong.  OP, I think you would probably be well served by reading up on some of the core principles of JS objects/types and how they work behind the scenes.  It is a strange idea to come to StackOverflow for help, then tell the 5+ people who try to help you that they are ALL wrong and that you know better.

Comment: I get a reference error, because you didn't initialize `person2`

Comment: how about you run it using the code from the example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701088/how-do-you-declare-a-string-indexed-associative-array-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment133548377_75701088:~:text=object%20property%20accessor) you gave?

Comment: Where is `person2` coming from?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev he provided it in his example, just follow the link

Answer (score 1):

"Associative arrays" are not a thing here.

This type:

```
Record<string, string>
```

Is an object type that has string keys, and properties have string values.

```
type bla = Record<string, string>

const blubb: bla = {} // note this is an object literal, not an array.
blubb.edfefe = "2"
console.log(blubb.edfefe) // "2"
```

---

Or perhaps you want [a `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

```
const blubb = new Map<string, string>()
blubb.set('edfefe', "2")
console.log(blubb.get('edfefe')) // "2"
```

Comment: no, i do not, but thanks

Comment: just give it a try in plain javascript versus typescript: const lol = []; lol["ROFL"] = 2; Array.isArray(lol);

Comment: That is the [object property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).  The syntax is the same as that used by arrays, but it's not the same stuff behind the scenes.  For example, if you do `const lol = []; lol["ROFL"]=2; console.log(lol.length)`, you are going to get 0.  You are essentially hacking your own custom property onto a JS array object, which is possible in JS because nothing is typed and anything goes.  In TS, you can't do this, because TS understands what an "array" is, and will not let you hack things so easily.

Comment: That is not adding an item to an associative array. That is setting an arbitrary property of an array to some arbitrary value. For example `for (const val of lol) {...}` would not include `2` in its iteration, because it's not actually in the array data. Javascript let's you do all kind type unsafe things. Typescript is used to enforce better ways. Setting arbitrary properties on arrays is a bad idea and you should avoid it.

Comment: @AlexWayne why is that if this is the only purpose i am using it for - without altering the prototypes? in itself it is an associative array.

Comment: @Jake try this with your example console.log(Array.isArray(person2));

Comment: That's what a javascript object is. It is a collection of key/value pairs. `const obj = {}; obj.foo = 2; console.log(obj.foo) // 2`. You only want an array if you want an ordered list of things that come with methods for managing that ordered list.

Comment: @AlexWayne sure, what do you get if you run console.log(Array.isArray(obj)); btw, you get an ordered list if you iterate through the values of the map

Comment: You would get `false`, because a plain object created as an object literal (like `{}`) is not array.

Comment: I would not allocate more memory, as arrays in JS _are_ objects. In fact, it would probably be less, as it would not have the overhead of being an array.

Comment: Worrying about the memory overhead of various data structures is fine, but if you don't understand what that overhead is and how those data structures work, then you will be optimizing based on incorrect assumptions. I would recommend not worrying about memory utilization until you are sure there is a problem, then you can measure and optimize from there.

Comment: Done some experimenting with the Chrome profiler. Not sure about plain objects vs plain arrays, but an instance of an empty class that extends `Object` is 68 bytes while that of an empty class that extends `Array` is 56 bytes. However, with 8 instances of each, the `Object` one is 96 bytes total (12 bytes each) and the `Array` one is 128 bytes (16 bytes each).

Comment: And engines can optimize some cases, and not others. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for object [index signatures](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-index-signatures/)?

`const arr = {[key: string]: string};`

Comment: no, i am not. thanks.